# Replace the Keys in a dictionary by Integers

Tags: python, dictionary

```
my_dict = {k:v for k, v in sorted_freq} # sorted_freq is a list containing key:value. 
{'like': 4870,
'taste': 4508,
'good': 3569,
'flavor': 3449,
'one': 3217,
'product': 3197,
'use': 3165,
'love': 3141,
'great': 3056,
'eat': 1614...}
```

How do I replace the Key in this dictionary by natural numbers starting from 1 for all the Keys in dictionary?

```
 [('like', 4870),
 ('tast', 4508),
 ('good', 3569),
 ('flavor', 3449),
 ('one', 3217),
 ('product', 3197),
 ('use', 3165),
 ('love', 3141),
 ('great', 3056),
 'get', 2400)...]
```

Comment: How do you know how to order these numbers? Dictionaries are not sorted in all versions of python

Comment: can you show us what did you try and what error you are getting?

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered! If you just want integers from a start range to an end range without worrying what their values are, we can help.

Comment: @patrickhaugh I disagree with that duplicate. It's too much of a leap to apply to this problem. It doesn't even apply to dictionaries.

Comment: Can you tell me how to replace the 'Key' to integers such as 1, 2, 3,... ?

Comment: Instead of replacing the key in the dictionary, *create* the dictionary using `enumerate` with your sorted list.  That way, even though the dictionary will not be ordered, the numbers will be.

Comment: @roganjosh I disagree.  I think the solution sought after here is the creation of a dict `{i: v for i, (k, v) in enumerate(sorted_freq, 1)}`, and the only part of that missing from the code in the question is `enumerate`

Comment: @patrickhaugh but as a direct dupe it ignores the order issues inherent to dictionaries. I'm just not sure the logical link is so clear for someone who might stumble over this question, since they probably wouldn't be searching this problem if they have the necessary understanding in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If starting from a dictionary**:

You can try using `enumerate` in a dictionary comprehension, but be aware that dictionaries are not garanteed to be ordered [depending on the version of python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/6671176):

```
{i:v for i,(k,v) in enumerate(my_dict.items(), 1)}

{1: 4870, 2: 4508, 3: 3569, 4: 3449, 5: 3217, 6: 3197, 7: 3165, 8: 3141, 9: 3056, 10: 1614}
```

**If Starting from a list of tuples (as you just posted in your edit):**

```
sorted_freq = [('like', 4870),
 ('tast', 4508),
 ('good', 3569),
 ('flavor', 3449),
 ('one', 3217),
 ('product', 3197),
 ('use', 3165),
 ('love', 3141),
 ('great', 3056),
 ('get', 2400)]


{i:v for i,(k,v) in enumerate(sorted_freq, 1)}
```